# VirtualBoxでドラッグ＆ドロップができなくて困っています。

Tags: virtualbox

よろしくお願いします。
VirtualBoxでドラッグ＆ドロップができなくて困っています。
マルチポストとなり非常に申し訳ありませんが、
[ゲストからホストへのドラッグ＆ドロップができません。](http://vboxmania.net/content/%E3%82%B2%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%83%9B%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%82%B0%EF%BC%86%E3%83%89%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%80%82-0)
解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただけないでしょうか？

ホストOS:Windows 10
ゲストOS:Ubuntu16.04
使用ソフト:VirtualBox-5.1.6-110634-Win

で

### ゲストOS:Ubuntu16.04→ホストOS:Windows 10へ

**フォルダ**をドラッグ＆ドロップを使用としたら以下のようなエラーメッセージが表示されました。

```
ゲストからホストへのドラッグ＆ドロップの操作に失敗しました。

Another drop operation already is in progress.
終了コード :E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057)
コンポーネント:GuestDnDSourceWrap
インターフェース:IGuestDnDSource {dedfb5d9-4c1b-edf7-fdf3-c1be6827dc28}
呼び出し先:IDnDSource {d23a9ca3-42da-c94b-8aec-21968e08355d}
```

**ファイル**をドラッグ＆ドロップを使用としたら以下のようなエラーメッセージが表示されました。

```
ゲストからホストへのドラッグ＆ドロップの操作に失敗しました。

Current drop operation still in progress.
終了コード :E_FAIL (0x80004005)
コンポーネント:GuestDnDSourceWrap
インターフェース:IGuestDnDSource {dedfb5d9-4c1b-edf7-fdf3-c1be6827dc28}
呼び出し先:IDnDSource {d23a9ca3-42da-c94b-8aec-21968e08355d}
```

### ホストOS:windows10-64bit→ゲストOS:Ubuntu16.04LTS-64bitへフォルダをドラッグ＆ドロップ

```
データのドロップ…Droping Data
```

のウィンドウが表示され進捗バーがずっと0％のままになります。

1時間以上放置していても一向に進む気配がありません。
Guest　Addition CD の挿入はきちんとできていて、テキストだけならクリップボード共有はできています。

これらの原因と解決方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: おれもそれできなくてこまってるから解決できないんだよな。解決できるといいな

Answer (score 1):

以下を試してみて下さい。

- VM メニューの "Devices" → "Drag and Drop" が "Bidirectional" になっていることを確認する。
- エクスプローラ explorer.exe を**管理者権限**で起動する (`C:\Windows\explorer.exe` を管理者として開く)。
- 管理者権限で起動したエクスプローラを使ってドラッグ・アンド・ドロップする。

また superuser 上の類似質問 ["Drag and drop doesn't work between host and VirtualBox on Windows 7"](https://superuser.com/q/1131746/680903) によると、ゲスト OS を一度シャットダウンしてもう一度起動する必要があるかもしれないとのことです。

#### 参考

VirtualBox の[ドラッグ・アンド・ドロップに関するマニュアル](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-dnd)には以下のように書かれています。

1. > For security reasons drag and drop can be configured at runtime on a per-VM basis either using the "Drag and Drop" menu item in the "Devices" menu of the virtual machine or VBoxManage.
   >
   > (和訳) セキュリティの観点から、ドラッグ・アンド・ドロップ機能は実行時に VM ごとに設定できるようになっています。VM のメニューの "Devices" にある "Drag and Drop" から操作するか、VBoxManage を使ってください。
2. > On Windows hosts, dragging and dropping content from **UAC-elevated (User Account Control)** programs to non-UAC-elevated programs and vice versa is now allowed. So when starting VirtualBox with Administrator privileges then drag and drop will not work with the Windows Explorer which runs with regular user privileges by default.
   >
   > (和訳) ホストが Windows の場合、**UAC (ユーザーアカウント制御)** で権限昇格されたプログラムとそうでないプログラムの間で相互にドラッグ・アンド・ドロップすることも許されています。したがってもし VirtualBox を管理者権限で起動した場合、デフォルト通り一般ユーザーの権限で起動された Windows Explorer との間のドラッグ・アンド・ドロップは上手く機能しません。